# What would happen if you copy two 60MB files one after another into a 100MB Truecrypt file container

Tags: truecrypt

What would happen if you copy two 60MB files one after
another into a 100MB Truecrypt file container

Answer (score 2):

You would run out of space while copying the second one, and it would most likely complain and error out - same as any other filesystem.